# 7-Mode snapmirror status post link change

Tags: storage, replication, netapp, ontap

In a Netapp with a snapmirror relationship to another Netapp in 7-mode, what are my options of checking replication performance through Data Ontap? We upgraded the link and want to know how snapmirror performs after the change.

Comment: For netapp questions, you might want to consider joining the toasters-administrators mailing list, and asking on there. The list's at http://www.teaparty.net/mailman/listinfo/toasters (disclaimer: I started this list, in 1997, and still administer it).

Comment: +1 for toasters. It's by far the best way to ask and answer questions about Netapp.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it a few ways- first, check a `snapmirror status -l` command will tell you the completion time for the last snapmirror as well as the current progress in KB and current lag (which you can use to calculate the current speed).

If you have all your traffic on a specific interface, you can use `ifstat` to measure its current speed, but that's measured in frames per second, not KB/s, and not everyone isolates their snapmirror traffic.